Do we want hats?
In 2011, the Gaming Stack Exchange hosted an event called Hat Dash, where users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges):

Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear". For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora with pen) to the editor.
This year, Stack Exchange is expanding the promotion to any site that wants to participate.
Here's the run down:

The event will run from 19 December 2012 to 4 January 2013.
Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on http://winterba.sh. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.
Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an "I hate hats" option available.
The only visual change to the site itself will be the presence of the hats and the "I hate hats" button in the footer.

We need to let Stack Exchange know by 28 November 2012, so vote away on if you want hats.
(This has been shamelessly stolen from Programmers SE.)

To all users: Vote and share your opinion please!

I know this is a bit late, but I would've voted no. There are simply not enough active users here to warrant inclusion of hats.

@JamesJiao It worked on other similarly sized sites. :)

Chinese SE has opted out from the Hats proposal.

It's a No from me.
I think we don't have a solid enough community of regulars yet. I think it would be like an in-joke that nobody feels part of.
I also think because we have many new people coming here, they might guess that this is something which is part of the regular site and may not like it and leave.
Third reason, with a new site it's easy to get distracted and we are currently trying to establish the community and how people interact with the site and respect for the site. It's OK to have a fun casual day when everything is rolling along nicely, but when we spend effort trying to get everyone to follow the rules it seems odd to turn around and have something which seems silly and layed back.
I'm not totally against the idea if others want it, but I think it would be best done at a later time when we have a more solid community.

The hats will be given if you contribute to the site, as with badges, same functioning... I don't see it as silly. It's just an idea to encourage people to do good things so they can have the hat. What is bad about this? :P

I vote yes. I think it might help the commitment of our fellow users and we can also have fun once in a while. 
Who doesn't like it can still opt out, so why not?

I want hats to keep my head warm.
